# Import files into workbook using For Loop. Check that missing file matches selected file

Tags: vb.net, excel

I wrote the following procedure to import, copy and paste the information from 5 workbooks into their designated worksheets of my main workbook.  It is extremely important that the imported files are copied and pasted on the correct sheet, otherwise, my whole project's calculations fail.

The procedure is written so that if the file to be imported is not found in the designated path an Open File Dialog opens and the user can browse for the file. Once the file is found, the procedure imports that file into the main workbook.

It all works fine, but I jus realized that if a file is missing and the user checks an file name in the directory, it will bring in that file and paste it on the workbook. This is a problem, and I do not know how to prevent or warn the user from importing the wrong file.

In other words my loop starts as `For n As Long = 1 to 5 Step 1`  If the file that is missing is `n=3 or statusReport.xls` and the Open File Dialog opens, the user can select any file on that directory or any other and pasted on the designated sheet. What I want is to warn the user that it has selected a file not equal to `n=3 or statusReport.xls`

Here is the functions for the 5 worksheets to be imported and the sheets to be pasted on:

```
Public Function DataSheets(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

        'This function indexes both the data employee and position
        'export sheets from Payscale.
        '@param DataSheets, are the sheets to index


        Select Case Index

            Case 1 : Return xlWSEmployee
            Case 2 : Return xlWSPosition
            Case 3 : Return xlWSStatusReport
            Case 4 : Return xlWSByDepartment
            Case 5 : Return xlWSByBand

        End Select

        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")

    End Function

    Public Function GetImportFiles(Index As Long) As String

        'This function houses the 5 files
        'used to import data to the project
        '@param GetImportFiles, are the files to be 
        'imported and pasted on the DataSheets

        Select Case Index

            Case 1 : Return "byEmployee.csv"
            Case 2 : Return "byPosition.csv"
            Case 3 : Return "statusReport.xls"
            Case 4 : Return "byDepartment.csv"
            Case 5 : Return "byband.csv"

        End Select

        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")


    End Function
```

This is the procedure to import, copy and paste the files. It is heavily commented for my own sanity and for those trying to figure out what is going on. I also noted below where I need to insert the check to make sure that the file selected equals `n`

```
    'This procedure imports the Client Listing.xlsx sheet. The procedure checks if the file is
            'in the same directory as the template. If the file is not there, a browser window appears to allow the user
            'to browse for the missing file. A series of message boxes guide the user through the process and
            'verifies that the user picked the right file. The user can cancel the import at any time.

            'Worksheet and Workbook Variables
            Dim xlDestSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
            Dim strImportFile As String
            Dim xlWBSource As Object = Nothing
            Dim xlWBImport As Object = Nothing


            'Loop through the 5 sheets and files

            For n As Long = 1 To 5 Step 1

                strImportFile = xlWBPath & "\" & GetImportFiles(n)
                xlDestSheet = DataSheets(n)

                'Convert the indexed sheet name to a string 
                'so that it can be passed through the xlWB.Worksheets paramater

                Dim strDestSheetName As String = xlDestSheet.Name

                'If the file is found, then import, copy and paste the
                'data into the corresponding sheets
                If Len(Dir(strImportFile)) > 0 Then

                    xlWBSource = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook
                    xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                    xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                    xlWBImport.Close()

                Else

                    'If a sheet is missing, prompt the user if they 
                    'want to browse for the file.

                    'Messagbox variables
                    Dim msbProceed As MsgBoxResult
                    Dim strVmbProceedResults As String = ("Procedure Canceled. Your project will now close")
                    Dim strPrompt As String = " source file does not exist." & vbNewLine & _
                        "Press OK to browse for the file or Cancel to quit"

                    'If the user does not want to browse, then close the workbook, no changes saved.
                    msbProceed = MsgBox("The " & strImportFile & strPrompt, MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Verify Source File")

                    If msbProceed = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
                        msbProceed = MsgBox(strVmbProceedResults, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

                        xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                        Exit Sub

                    Else

                        'If the user does want to browse, then open the File Dialog
                        'box for the user to browse for the file

                        'Open Fil Dialog box variable and settings
                        Dim ofdGetOpenFileName As New OpenFileDialog()

                        ofdGetOpenFileName.Title = "Open File " & strImportFile
                        ofdGetOpenFileName.InitialDirectory = xlWBPath
                        ofdGetOpenFileName.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.csv)| *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx; *.xlsm"
                        ofdGetOpenFileName.FilterIndex = 2
                        ofdGetOpenFileName.RestoreDirectory = True

                        'If the user presses Cancel on the box, warn that no
                        'file has been selected and the workbook will close

                        If ofdGetOpenFileName.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then

                            'Message box variables
                            Dim msbContinue As MsgBoxResult
                            Dim strAlert As String = ("You have not selected a workbook." & vbNewLine & _
                                                      "The project will now close without saving changes")

                            'Once the user presses OK, close the file and do not save changes
                            msbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No Workbook Seletected")
                            xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                            Exit Sub

                        Else

                            'If the user does select the file, then import the file
                            'copy and paste on workbook.

'***Here is where I need to check that strImportFile =n, if it does not warn the user******

                            strImportFile = ofdGetOpenFileName.FileName
                            xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                            xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                            xlWBImport.Close()

                        End If

                        Try

                            'Import the remainder of the files
                            xlWBSource = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook
                            xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                            xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                            xlWBImport.Close()

                        Catch ex As Exception

                            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unexpected Error")

                        End Try
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated and/or any recommendations to improve my code as well.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a possible application for a GoTo - objected to by many but it does still have its uses!!

Compare the file name with an if statement and if incorrect notify the user and return them to the browse dialog.

```
Else
Retry:
                    'If the user does want to browse, then open the File Dialog
                    'box for the user to browse for the file

                    'Open Fil Dialog box variable and settings
                    Dim ofdGetOpenFileName As New OpenFileDialog()

                    ofdGetOpenFileName.Title = "Open File " & strImportFile
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.InitialDirectory = xlWBPath
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.csv)| *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx; *.xlsm"
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.FilterIndex = 2
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.RestoreDirectory = True

                    'If the user presses Cancel on the box, warn that no
                    'file has been selected and the workbook will close

                    If ofdGetOpenFileName.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then

                        'Message box variables
                        Dim msbContinue As MsgBoxResult
                        Dim strAlert As String = ("You have not selected a workbook." & vbNewLine & _
                                                  "The project will now close without saving changes")

                        'Once the user presses OK, close the file and do not save changes
                        msbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No Workbook Seletected")
                        xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                        Exit Sub

                    Else

                        'If the user does select the file, then import the file
                        'copy and paste on workbook.

'***Here is where I need to check that strImportFile =n, if it does not warn the user******

                        strImportFile = ofdGetOpenFileName.FileName
                        If strImportFile <> GetImportFiles(n) then
                            msgbox("You have not selected the correct file please try again")
                            GoTo Retry
                        End If

                        xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                        xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                        xlWBImport.Close()

                    End If
```

Hope this helps....

---

Should have also added to this it is advisable to put the `GoTo` as the result of a query to the user otherwise they can find themselves in an endless loop if they are unable to locate the correct file!

Comment: Thanks, if you a sample code I would love to see it. I have never used the GoTo statement before.

Comment: Thanks I actually was able to work my way through it and figure it out.